# Error running Pyserial

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino, pyserial

I just installed Pyserial 2.6 and I have Python 2.7.3 unfortunately it either did not install correctly or I am not using it correctly. I installed it through terminal using the line

```
sudo easy_install pyserial
```

Unfortunately it gave me 2  warnings:

```
warning: no files found matching 'examples/miniterm.py'
warning: no files found matching 'test/test_io_lib.py'
```

Other than that it seemed to install correctly.

When I run this in Python I keep getting the  farther below error

```
import serial
serial_input = serial.Serial('/dev/tty/.usbmodem3d241',9600)
while True:
    ser.readline()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ben/Documents/Arduino_to_Python.py", line 5, in <module>
    serial_input = serial.Serial('/dev/tty/.usbmodem3d241',9600)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/serial/serialutil.py", line 261, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/serial/serialposix.py", line 278, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
SerialException: could not open port /dev/tty/.usbmodem3d241: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/dev/tty/.usbmodem3d241'
```

Whatever serial port I try it never seems to work. I have tried the ones in the Arduino program Tools>Serial Port and all of the prompts at http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/shortintro.html#opening-serial-ports

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: And you are certain the path does exist? Look at `/dev/tty` in a shell.

Comment: Does `dmesg | grep usbmodem` give any clues as to what the path is for the device?

Comment: I tried this from the pyserial website to no avial. Anythoughts toward  what the path should be?                                                    >>> ser = serial.Serial()
>>> ser.baudrate = 19200
>>> ser.port = 0
>>> ser.open()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    ser.open()
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/serial/serialposix.py", line 278, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
SerialException: could not open port 0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/cuad0'

Comment: Martijn I coped it into the python shell and got a Syntax error? Any thoughts about what the correct path should be for the serial_input line?

Comment: What did you copy? `dmesg` is a Linux command line tool, not a python command. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I ran it in Terminal? I reinstalled everything using Pyserial 2.5 and these lines in terminal [cope] tar xfvz pyserial-2.5.tar.gz
cd pyserial-2.5
sudo python setup.py install [/code]

Comment: tar xfvz pyserial-2.5.tar.gz

Comment: tar xfvz pyserial-2.5.tar.gz
    cd pyserial-2.5
    sudo python setup.py install

Comment: There is no need to reinstall python here. You need to figure out what the correct device path is instead. `dmesg` may help in that, because any USB device attached will generate a message in that log.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So what should happen when I run it in terminal, because nothing is happening right now except for this error message Unable to obtain kernel buffer: Operation not permitted
usage: sudo dmesg. When I change it to to sudo dmseg... nothing happens?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Now it is working, but spits out a massive amount of information. What should I be looking for in that? I have an Arduino Mega plugged in.

Comment: See posts like See posts like http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,39052.0.html; you are looking for USB events to tell you the correct name of the device to open.

Answer (score 0):

This `serial_input = serial.Serial('/dev/tty/.usbmodem3d241',9600)` should be without the additional `/.` between `/dev/tty` and `usbmodem3d241`.

Also, open your console and go see if `ttyusbmodem3d241` exists. In the console type `cd /dev` then `ls` and see if it is listed.

Answer (score 0):

Go to arduino ide-> tools from menu on top left -> ports -> look at what your port says under serial ports mine says COM3(Arduino.....)
In python
  serial_input = serial.Serial('portName',9600)

mine was COM3
  serial_input = serial.Serial('COM3',9600)

I know it's too late, but just added it anyway.